# Python on WordPress / Woocommerce upload pictures

Tags: python, php, wordpress, github, woocommerce

Hello I am new to Python and I would like to know if it was possible to use and install Python packages / libraries from Github on WordPress, because I would like to use Python to be able to remove the background of the products that will be published via the woocommerce plugin . Thanks in advance for your reply and your help.

Comment: Typically, web servers with WordPress on them do not allow you to run python scripts on them, you'll need to customize your host server to [allow this functionality](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/webservers.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try to find a solution, with this.